# Can't get if and else statement to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

I've been playing around with my if and else statement but it's always just providing one.

First try

```
<% if @albumable == @user %>
 <%= link_to "Edit", edit_community_album_path(@albumable, album), class:  "album_edit" %>
<% else %>
 <%= link_to "Ediiiit", edit_user_album_path(@albumable, album), class: "album_edit" %>
<% end %>
```

Second try

```
<% if @community == @community_id %>
```

Albumable will either be a user_id or community_id. When I play around with the code I only get 1 result from the two for both the user album edit page and the community album edit page. I don't understand how I'll be able to making an if statement if it isn't within the community page, it should produce the else statement. All help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring this code to remove the if/else statement altogether. For example, the following provides the exact same functionality:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, @albumable, album], class: "album_edit" %>
```

You can read more about this at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Comment: Thank you sooo much for that example. It works perfectly and it's much simpler than trying to create an if/else statement. Thank you a lot. I'm going to read the link you provided to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `id` values instead. Depending on how you loaded those variables with records, Ruby might not think they're equal.